# split SASS param with fallback to default if the params are shorter

Tags: sass

I have a sass mixin that typically receives params such as :

```
1 1 33%
```

(no quotes around)
I can split these values using nth($values, 1); etc

but sometimes the mixin is called with only one value in the param

```
1
```

nth() will then fail with : index out of bounds for `nth($list, $n)`

What is an elegant way to fallback to some default values if the mixin is called with a one value param ?

Comment: Do you have an actual use case here for trying to select a specific index like this?

Comment: I was about to delete the question but it is a mixin for flex, it can be feed with various manners

Comment: You shouldn't *need* to select specific indexes of the value for the flex property under any circumstance... unless you're writing a mixin that provides the old 2009 properties.  Even then, you only need the 1st element of the list.

Comment: IE11 doesn't support calc() in shorthand declaration. Therefore I want the mixin to generate the individual properties.

Comment: Why are you using `calc()` at all?  Seriously, there's no reason to be using this in combination with the flex property.  There's rarely a legitimate need to use it any other time, either.

Comment: it is hard to explain with text, but its is a design that is based on 3 cols of equal width + margins. So there is cases where it is needed to add/remove those margins from the calculation.

Comment: You clearly don't understand how the flex property works if you think you need calc for this.

Comment: I am not referring to margins as css margins but design margin. Would "gutter" be more explicit ? in this design cols have fexible width, but gutters have fixed width, hence the use of calc.

Comment: You have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, which is what I'm trying to get at.  While your "solution" works, it's not a good one at all for the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: thanks for your attention here, but I am pretty sure to understand correctly X. I know from experience that while doing tech support we like to redefined the issues exposed, but here I don't think it is the case. I want to push what is possible with the tech in order to implement finer design. Think about the different weights that a font can have. It is designer work, not simply proportional stretching. Some parts do stretch, some other dont. Again thanks for your attention here, exchange is better than lonely rambling.

Comment: Again, you're trying to solve the wrong problem.  But hey, [what do I know](http://jsfiddle.net/bctys2rv/)?  Maybe you're right, [writing a dirty hack is clearly the only way to solve this problem](http://jsfiddle.net/bctys2rv/1/).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with

```
$grow: 1;
$shrink: 1;
$basis: 0px;
@if length($values) >= 1 {
    $grow: nth($values, 1);
}
@if length($values) >= 2 {
    $shrink: nth($values, 2);
}

@if length($values) >= 3 {
    $basis: nth($values, 3);
}
```

but getting the defaults right seems a bit more complex logic: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/

but that is now outside the scope of this question which isn't specific to flexbox.